# How to convert json object of array of objects?

Tags: javascript, json

1)I have sample data like [{admin=custom}, {aa@g.com=1}, {main@gmail.com=free}].

2. I want to convert above to [{'admin' : 'custom'}, {'aa@g.com':'1'}, {'main@gmail.com':'free'}]\

I want to achieve 2 point from 1st point.

Comment: `{admin=custom}` this syntax is invalid. Please read [ask] and how to create [mcve].

Comment: the sample data is not valid JSON. To turn JSON into JS, use `JSON.parse(myJSONString)`

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data is not valid JSON. To get a js array/object from it, you can convert it to JSON with a regex.

```js
sampleData = "[{admin=custom}, {aa@g.com=1}, {main@gmail.com=free}]"
jsonData = sampleData.replace(/\{([^={}]+)=([^={}]+)\}/, "{'$1':'$2'}")
objectData = JSON.parse(jsonData)
```

Breaking down the regex:

```
/
 \{          //escaped open bracket
   (         //first capture group ($1), left hand side.
    [^={}]+  //any number of character which are not "=" or braces
           ) //end first capture group
            =  //don't capture the equals
             ([^={}]+)   //second capture group ($2), same as the first
                      \} //escaped closing bracket
                        /
```